# Get value selected select2 <li> not option

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

I use select2, and i want to get the value of my option when i select a tag, but my select2 output is like that
"span" "UL" "li" and when i search here i found one say that you can get your value of option like this `jQuery("#service").select2('data');` but i get a empty alert
html:

```
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3">
    <input type="hidden"  value="search" class="search_icon">
</div>
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-5">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Que cherchez-vous ?</label>
    <select name="services[]" id="service" class="form-control select2-multiple col-lg-5 col-md-9" multiple>
        <?php if ( !empty( $post_id ) ) {
            foreach ($post_id as $value) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo($value->ID);?>"><?php echo($value->post_title);?></option>
         <?php
              }
         }               
         ?>

     </select>
</div>
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-2">
    <input type="button" value="search" class="search_icon">
</div>
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3">
    <input type="hidden"  value="search">
</div>
```

and this my script :

```
   <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery('#service').select2({
          minimumInputLength: 1,
          width: '100%',
          tags: true
        });
        var option_val = jQuery("#service").select2('data');            
        jQuery('.search_icon').on('click', function() {
            alert(option_val);
        }); 
  </script>
```

Comment: what's wrong with `$('#service').val()`?  select 2 should update the actual select.  Use it directly in the click - not where you have declared the other value otherwise the value won't update after dom ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the current selected value in the list when you click you have to use `select2('data')` inside the click event like :

```
jQuery('.search_icon').on('click', function() {
    var option_val = jQuery("#service").select2('data');

    alert(option_val[0].text); //text
    //Or
    //alert( jQuery("#service option:selected").text() ); //text
    //Or
    //alert( jQuery("#service").val() ); //value
});
```

Comment: i get [object object] alert

Comment: Since it will return an object, try `alert(option_val[0].text)`

Comment: You could also use `jQuery("#service option:selected").text();`

Comment: i can alert value ? not text?

Comment: `jQuery("#service").val();`

Comment: i do this but My fault is a charge a var after event click. thank's a lot for help :D